# Ansible : host in multiple groups

Tags: ansible

I have a host in 2 groups : pc and Servers
I have 2 group_vars (pc and servers) with, in each the file packages.yml
These files define the list of packages to be installed on pc hosts and on servers hosts

I have a role to install default package

The problem is : only the group_vars/pc/packages.yml is take into account by the role task, packages from group_vars/servers/packages.yml are not installed

Of course what I want is installation of packages defined for pc and servers

I do not know if it is a bug or a feature ...

Thanks for your help

here is the configuration :

```
# file: production
[pc]
armen
kerbel
kerzo

[servers]
kerbel

---
# packages on servers
packages:
  - lftp
  - mercurial

---
# packages on pc
packages:
  - keepassx
  - lm-sensors
  - hddtemp
```

Comment: It does not directly address your issue, this tool will create a graph so you can see how your host got assigned to a group https://willthames.github.io/2014/04/03/an-ansible-inventory-grapher.html

Comment: What version of Ansible are you using?

Comment: Latest ansible to date is 1.6.1

Answer (score 8):

It's not a bug. According to the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) about variable precedence, you shouldn't define a variable in multiple places and try to keep it simple. Michael DeHaan (Ansible's lead dev) [responded](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ansible-project/ycLMEb5lNJ4/eJqvXIBWQJkJ) to a similar question on this topic:

> Generally I find the purpose of plays though to bind hosts to roles, so the individual roles should contain the package lists.

I would use roles as it's a bit cleaner IMO.

If you really want (and this is NOT the recommended way), you can set the [hash_behaviour](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour) option in ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
hash_behaviour = merge
```

This will cause the merging of two values when a hash (dict) is redefined, instead of replacing the old value with the new one. This does NOT work on lists, though, so you'll need to create a hash of lists, like:

group_vars/all/package.yml:

```
packages:
    all: [pkg1, pkg2]
```

group_vars/servers/package.yml:

```
packages:
    servers: [pkg3, pkg4]
```

Looping though that in the playbook is a bit more complex though.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use such scheme. You should set  the hash_behaviour option in ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
hash_behaviour = merge
```

In addition, you have to use dictionaries instead of lists. To prevent duplicates I recommend to use names as keys, for example:

group_vars/servers/packages.yml:

```
packages:
 package_name1:
 package_name2:
```

group_vars/pc/packages.yml:

```
packages:
 package_name3:
 package_name4:
```

And in a playbook task (| default({}) - for an absent "package" variable case):

```
- name: install host packages
  yum: name={{ item.key }} state=latest
  with_dict: packages | default({})
```

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"Installation of packages defined for pc and servers."***

A: The section **Solution** below describes a comprehensive and transparent framework for how to selectively merge lists.

---

- **Detail description of the problem**

Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[pc]
armen
kerbel
kerzo

[servers]
kerbel
```

and the variable *packages* defined for the groups *pc* and *server*, for example, in *group_vars/*/packages.yml*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/pc/packages.yml 
packages:
  - keepassx
  - lm-sensors
  - hddtemp
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/servers/packages.yml 
packages:
  - lftp
  - mercurial
```

the play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: packages
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
ok: [armen] => 
  packages: [keepassx, lm-sensors, hddtemp]
ok: [kerzo] => 
  packages: [keepassx, lm-sensors, hddtemp]
ok: [kerbel] => 
  packages: [lftp, mercurial]
```

The host *kerbel* keeps only 2 items in the list *packages* despite being a member of both groups *pc* and *server*. The lists do not merge. The *group_vars* directories are read in alphabetical order and override each other. Hence, the variables in *group_vars/servers/packages.yml* **replace** the variables in *group_vars/pc/packages.yml*

---

- **Quick and dirty**

There is an option to merge dictionaries. See [*DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour). The default is ***replace***. You can set it to ***merge***. This doesn't help you because only dictionaries are merged not lists. The other answers here describe how to convert the variables *packages*  from lists to dictionaries and merge them. Except for the fact that this doesn't solve the problem with the lists, you should **avoid *merge*** because:

> It is the intention of the Ansible developers to eventually deprecate and remove this setting, but it is being kept as some users do heavily rely on it. New projects should avoid ‘merge’.

In addition to this, it is also good to keep in mind that the option `ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR=merge` makes the dictionaries merge globally. As a result, the [precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) of the type dictionary variables won't work.

If you still want to proceed this way the implementation is simple. Declare the dictionaries

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/pc/packages.yml
packages:
  keepassx:
  lm-sensors:
  hddtemp:
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/servers/packages.yml
packages:
  lftp:
  mercurial:
```

and list the keys. For example, the play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  pre_tasks:
    - set_fact:
        packages: "{{ packages.keys()|list }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: packages
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR=merge ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
ok: [kerbel] => 
  packages: [keepassx, lm-sensors, hddtemp, lftp, mercurial]
ok: [armen] => 
  packages: [keepassx, lm-sensors, hddtemp]
ok: [kerzo] => 
  packages: [keepassx, lm-sensors, hddtemp]
```

---

- **Solution**

There is a comprehensive and transparent framework for how to selectively merge lists. Create a dictionary of the variables per group and merge the selected lists on your own. Implementation requires:

- The declarations in *group_vars/all/group_dict_vars.yml*
- The 'instantiations' of the merged lists in pre_tasks *group_dict_create.yml*

For example, create a project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_dict_create.yml
├── group_vars
│   ├── all
│   │   └── group_dict_vars.yml
│   ├── pc
│   │   └── packages.yml
│   └── servers
│       └── packages.yml
├── hosts
└── pb.yml

4 directories, 7 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[pc]
armen
kerbel
kerzo

[servers]
kerbel
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/pc/packages.yml 
packages:
  - keepassx
  - lm-sensors
  - hddtemp
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/servers/packages.yml 
packages:
  - lftp
  - mercurial
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  pre_tasks:

    - import_tasks: group_dict_create.yml

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: packages
```

Declare variables in *group_vars/all/group_dict_vars.yml*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/group_dict_vars.yml
group_vars_dir: "{{ inventory_dir }}/group_vars"
group_names_all: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                     map('extract', hostvars, 'group_names')|
                     flatten|unique }}"
_group_dict: |
  {% filter from_yaml %}
  {% for group in group_names_all %}
    {{ group }}: {{ lookup('vars', 'groupvars_' ~ group) }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfilter %}
my_packages: "{{ group_names|map('extract', group_dict, 'packages')|flatten|unique }}"
# my_users: "{{ group_names|map('extract', group_dict, 'users')|flatten|unique }}"
```

- *group_vars_dir*: The directory [*group_vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) can be used either in the directory where the inventory or the playbook comes from. In this example, these directories are identical and we set it to [*inventory_dir*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html). In the loop, the task [*include_vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html#ansible-builtin-include-vars-module-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task) will read all YAML and JSON files from *group_vars/<group>* and will store the variables in the dictionary
  *groupvars_<group>*, where *<group>* are items of *group_names_all*.
- *group_names_all*: This is a list of all groups the *hosts* are members of. See [*group_names*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)
- *_group_dict*: Dictionary of all groups and their variables
- *my_packages*: Merge the lists of packages from the groups the host is a member of. If needed, use this variable as a pattern of how to merge other variables.

Run once a block of tasks delegated to the localhost that creates the dictionary and writes the file group_vars/all/group_dict.yml. 'Instantiate' (*set_fact*) the selected lists for each host.

```yaml
shell> cat group_dict_create.yml
- name: Create dictionary group_dict in group_vars/all/group_dict.yml

  block:

    - name: Create directory group_vars/all
      file:
        state: directory
        path: "{{ group_vars_dir }}/all"

    - include_vars:
        dir: "{{ group_vars_dir }}/{{ item }}"
        name: "groupvars_{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ group_names_all }}"

    - debug:
        var: _group_dict
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - name: Write group_dict to group_vars/all/group_dict.yml
      copy:
        dest: "{{ group_vars_dir }}/all/group_dict.yml"
        content: |
          group_dict:
            {{ _group_dict|to_nice_yaml(indent=2)|indent(2) }}

    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ group_vars_dir }}/all/group_dict.yml"

  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
  when: group_dict is not defined or group_dict_refresh|d(false)|bool

- set_fact:
    packages: "{{ my_packages }}"
    # users: "{{ my_users }}"
```

If the dictionary *group_dict* does not exist (the file *group_vars/all/group_dict.yml* has not been created yet) it will create the dictionary, write it to the file *group_vars/all/group_dict.yml*, and include it in the play. You can refresh *group_dict* by setting *group_dict_refresh=true* if you change the variables in *group_vars/<group>*.

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/group_dict.yml 
group_dict:
  pc:
    packages:
    - keepassx
    - lm-sensors
    - hddtemp
  servers:
    packages:
    - lftp
    - mercurial
```

The results, stored in the variable *my_packages*, are merged lists of *packages* by groups and override the variable *packages* for each host in the the task *set_fact*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
ok: [armen] => 
  packages: [keepassx, lm-sensors, hddtemp]
ok: [kerbel] => 
  packages: [keepassx, lm-sensors, hddtemp, lftp, mercurial]
ok: [kerzo] => 
  packages: [keepassx, lm-sensors, hddtemp]
```

**Notes**:

- Best practice is running *group_dict_create.yml* separately for all hosts and letting other playbooks use created *group_vars/all/group_dict.yml*
- The framework described here is idempotent.
- You can easily add other lists.

---

**Example**

Add variable *users* to *group_vars/<group>*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/pc/users.yml 
users:
  - alice
  - bob
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/servers/users.yml 
users:
  - carol
  - dave
```

, add the variable *my_users* to *group_vars/all/group_dict_vars.yml*

```yaml
my_users: "{{ group_names|map('extract', group_dict, 'users')|flatten|unique }}"
```

, and 'instantiate' the variable *users* in *group_dict_create.yml*

```yaml
- set_fact:
    packages: "{{ my_packages }}"
    users: "{{ my_users }}"
```

Refresh the dictionary *group_dict* for all hosts

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l all -e group_dict_refresh=true
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [armen] => 
  users: [alice, bob]
ok: [kerbel] => 
  users: [alice, bob, carol, dave]
ok: [kerzo] => 
  users: [alice, bob]
```