# Setup windows 10 workstation using Ansible installed on WSL

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have installed Ansible in the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) within my Windows 10 workstation.

My goal is configure both, WSL, and the Windows 10 itself.

I'm able to run playbooks against localhost, which connect and configures via SSH the WSL.

However I am not sure Ansible can run playbooks against the Windows host to be able to setup Windows itself (e.g. install packages using Chocolatey)

Is that even possible?  Or Ansible can only setup a windows node when is installed in a different Linux machine?

Answer (score 8):

Great! I was able to connect to my windows host after following those steps.

However, I had to solve two more issues before I was able to run ansible playbooks against both, WSL and windows host:

#### 1. Define connection for WSL

Windows host uses `ansible_connection=winrm`, but for WSL needs a different connection, I've set `ansible_connection=local`.

#### 2. Avoid connection var being overriden

The `ansible_connection` var is [overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525546/ansible-host-in-multiple-groups). This is because the var name and the host name is the same. This means that you can either run a playbook for WSL or for Windows host but not against both, as they need different connection.

To fix that you can either set [hash-behaviour](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour), or set two different host names for localhost under your WSL, `/etc/hosts`. I've done the second one:

```
127.0.0.1   wsl.local
127.0.0.1   windows.local
```

My `/etc/ansible/hosts`:

```
[wsl]
wsl.local 

[wsl:vars]
ansible_connection=local

[windows]
windows.local 
[windows:vars]
ansible_port=5985
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_transport=basic
ansible_user=<<ansible_user>>
ansible_password=<<ansible_password>>
```

Now I can run an ansible_playbook with tasks running against both, my windows host and my WSL. [Here](https://github.com/vecin2/ws_playbook) for more details on configuration.

Comment: If you are using `ansible-pull` which is great for that purpose, I would suggest to split the provisioning of WSL and Win in separate playbooks. Then in your playbook file you can target localhost but specify the connection in vars:
`vars:
 ansible_connection: local`
and for Win
`vars:
 ansible_connection: winrm
 ansible_port: 5984
 etc..`
This will leave your `ansible.cfg` untouched and will let you run the playbook without extra configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible.

1. First you must have WSL (which you do)
2. Next you need to install Ansible, but you need extra packages for using it with WinRM

   - Install pip `$ apt install python-pip`
   - Install pip winrm `$ pip install pywinrm`
   - Install xml parser `$ pip install xmltodict`
3. You need your WinRM setuped:

   - You need to make your network private as WinRM by default works only for Private or Domain networks. You can skip that by providing parameter to `Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck` but I dont suggest doing that.
   - Enable WinRM `Enable-PSRemoting` running it in the PowerShell in Windows.
   - Enable Basic Auth `Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic -Value $true`
   - Enable Unencrypted connection`Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Service\AllowUnencrypted -Value $true`
4. In WSL, add as vars to your playbook or group_vars

```
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_transport: basic
```

6. When running your playbook provide vars `ansible_user=your_win_user` and `ansible_password=your_win_user_pass` or hardcode them in the previous vars.

I use this setup to provision my machine from WSL. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/gmarokov/ansible-win-postinstall). Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to set `ansible_connection: local` somewhere you prefer: https://gist.github.com/alces/caa3e7e5f46f9595f715f0f55eef65c1
Separate playbooks/groups for Win and WSL(Linux).

Comment: Please accept the answer if did helped you :) Thanks