# Ansible group variables merging and overlapping

Tags: variables, ansible

I've been using Ansible for several years now and I keep struggling with the following topic.

Let me give you a simple example. I wrote a [role to handle installing packages](https://github.com/imp1sh/ansible_managemynetwork/tree/main/roles/ansible_packages). Sometimes it's required to define on a host level (*packages_installhost* variable) what packages shall be installed, other times it should be defined on a group level. Yet hosts can be part of several groups so what's the concept of Ansible on this? I'm convinced, Ansible has no concept at all for this every day requirement.

Back in the days I just defined the group based variable multiple times and let Ansible merge it, but that method got deprecated a while ago (*hash_behaviour=merge*). That came a bit as a shock to me, since that was the most intuitive approach I could think of.

Ever since then I built in [logic to merge the dicts / lists within the role](https://github.com/imp1sh/ansible_managemynetwork/blob/main/roles/ansible_packages/tasks/1prepare_install.yml), based upon their group memberships. That works really well but there are (at least) two problems left:

1. For the user it's counter intuitive to define the variable *packages_installgroup* in e.g *group_vars/all.yml* where every host has access to it. The user intuitively wants to define group based vars within the group var, e.g. *group_vars/environment_A.yml*.

2. For nearly every role I create, I have to write a considerable amount of logic for this to work. This is cumbersome and tedious.

In the end I want to have flexibility and power, meaning. The user of my role shall be able to just define vars, reference my role and then be happy. I'm convinced when the users feel the need to embed additional logic to his playbook, than my role is not good enough.

Comment: Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75530698/6482561)

Comment: "_I'm convinced, Ansible has no concept at all for this every day requirement._". The way Ansible address this in a very simple manner is the inventory and group_vars. See also [Inventory basics: formats, hosts, and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups) and [`group_vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence).

Comment: Regarding "_... defined the group based variable multiple times and let Ansible merge it, but that method got deprecated a while ago (`hash_behaviour=merge`). That came a bit as a shock to me, since that was the most intuitive approach I could think of_" and just for the further documentation, there is more information under [Ansible Pull #6300](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/63300) and [Ansible Issue #73089](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/73089).

Comment: For the record. The latest [default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#grouping-groups-parent-child-group-relationships) is still `Ansible merges the data from the multiple groups.`

Comment: Ansible clearly states that hash_behaviour=merge is deprecated and will be removed in future releases, so sadly this is no solution either.

Comment: This might be a good approach, yet it's not been updated in the last two years.
https://github.com/leapfrogonline/ansible-merge-vars

Answer (score 2):

The solution presented below was created to address our use case which closely matches yours. It requires only a little discipline in variable naming. Let's take your example where various host groups, hosts, and perhaps role defaults each want to have some packages installed. Define a list variable in each of the appropriate places, and name all the variables with the same prefix, but with a suffix unique to each place they are defined. With a prefix of `packages_` then you might end up with `packages_myhost`, `packages_group_a`, `packages_group_b`, `packages_group_q`, `packages_role_foo_defaults`, and `packages_role_bar_defaults`. There could be many more; these lets say are the ones visible to `myhost`.

None of these variables need to "be aware" of each other. You, however, need to ensure they have sufficiently unique suffixes for this technique to work. They come together in the task that actually installs packages. There, you merge the lists with something like the [mergevars](https://gist.github.com/utoddl/ae11ace7a020c3b0da00e2dce2522806) lookup plugin:

```
"{{ lookup('mergevars', regex='^packages_.*') }}"
```

In addition to the optional regular expression, `mergevars` will take variable names which it will merge in the order listed. Any explicitly listed variables whose names also match `regex` will only be merged once. Variables selected by `regex` will be merged after explicitly listed variables, and in alphabetical order by name.

```
"{{ lookup('mergevars', 'alpha_z', 'alpha_y', regex='^alpha_.*' }}"
```

`mergevars` is not limited to lists either. If your variables are dicts, it will merge them rather like the `combine` filter does. Just be sure all the variables are "shaped" the same way: all lists or all dicts.

You aren't limited to variable names either. You can pass in structured data, or pass in variables by value (i.e. unquoted) rather than by name. But in that case a `regex` that matches the same variable will not notice it's already included and will merge it twice, so be careful!

```
"{{ lookup('mergevars', {'a': 3}, beta_dict, {'z': 99}, regex='^alpha_dicts_.*' }}"
```

With at least one `-v`, `mergevars` will log the order and names of variables it's merging. There's also a `dedup` option which de-duplicates resulting lists, and a `recursive` option for deeply merging dicts, both of which default to `true`. (So you needn't worry about group_vars and host_vars files that both request some of the same packages.)

Comment: Well yeah I could do that but it's only a different way of what I'm doing already to achieve the same goal.
I am searching for a built in concept that Ansible brings to its role/collection developers that targets the problem of wanting to define lists or dicts on different layers (group / host) that in the end will lead to a combined result that will just be there, out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow-up to Todd's answer, based on the same naming convention but using only stock ansible features, namely the [`varnames`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/varnames_lookup.html) and [`vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html) lookups.

Example project structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── inventories
│   └── default
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   ├── all
│       │   │   └── packages.yml
│       │   ├── linux
│       │   │   └── packages.yml
│       │   ├── physical_boxes
│       │   │   └── packages.yml
│       │   └── servers
│       │       └── packages.yml
│       └── hosts.yml
└── playbook.yml

7 directories, 6 files
```

**`inventories/default/hosts.yml`**

```yaml
---
linux:
  hosts:
    everest:
    galibier:
    annapurna:
    puymorens:
    eiger:
physical_boxes:
  hosts:
    everest:
    annapurna:
    puymorens:
servers:
  hosts:
    everest:
    galibier:
    eiger:
```

**`inventories/default/group_vars/linux/packages.yml`**

```yaml
---
packages_linux:
  - toto
  - pipo
  - bingo
```

**`inventories/default/group_vars/phisical_boxes/packages.yml`**

```yaml
---
packages_physical_boxes:
  - pear
  - mango
```

**`inventories/default/group_vars/servers/packages.yml`**

```yaml
---
packages_servers:
  - joe
  - william
  - jack
  - Averell
```

**`inventories/default/group_vars/all/packages.yml`** (note: [`q` is an alias to `query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#forcing-lookups-to-return-lists-query-and-wantlist-true))

```yaml
---
packages_all:
  - earth
  - wind
  - fire

_package_vars_to_merge: "{{ q('varnames', '^packages_.*$') | sort }}"

packages: >-
  {%- set packages_all = [] -%}
  {%- for _package_var in _package_vars_to_merge -%}
  {{ packages_all.append(lookup('vars', _package_var)) }}
  {%- endfor -%}
  {{ packages_all | flatten | sort | unique }}
```

We can test this with the following `playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Merge several packages vars example
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Debug the full list of packages for each host
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: packages
```

which called with the above example inventory gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/default/ playbook.yml 

PLAY [Merge several packages vars example] ***************************************************************

TASK [Debug the full list of packages for each host] *****************************************************
ok: [everest] => {
    "packages": [
        "Averell",
        "bingo",
        "earth",
        "fire",
        "jack",
        "joe",
        "mango",
        "pear",
        "pipo",
        "toto",
        "william",
        "wind"
    ]
}
ok: [galibier] => {
    "packages": [
        "Averell",
        "bingo",
        "earth",
        "fire",
        "jack",
        "joe",
        "pipo",
        "toto",
        "william",
        "wind"
    ]
}
ok: [annapurna] => {
    "packages": [
        "bingo",
        "earth",
        "fire",
        "mango",
        "pear",
        "pipo",
        "toto",
        "wind"
    ]
}
ok: [puymorens] => {
    "packages": [
        "bingo",
        "earth",
        "fire",
        "mango",
        "pear",
        "pipo",
        "toto",
        "wind"
    ]
}
ok: [eiger] => {
    "packages": [
        "Averell",
        "bingo",
        "earth",
        "fire",
        "jack",
        "joe",
        "pipo",
        "toto",
        "william",
        "wind"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************
annapurna                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
eiger                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
everest                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
galibier                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
puymorens                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: As I pointed out in my OP I don't want a solution where the user has to add logic. The user shall just use my role and not be concerned about how and which variables to merge.

Comment: ... and as pointed out by several persons above, it is not possible (unless you want to go back to an unmaintained and outdated version of ansible allowing `hash_behaviour=merge`). So if you don't want to use a custom plugin nor give a quite easy to follow naming convention and write once and for all a few lines in `group_vars/all`, I'm afraid you're totally stuck.